# What's the recommended way to structure WebService app?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, architecture

In a Java webapp, is there a best practice for storing XSD files and wsdl files?

1) What folder structure should be used storing XSD and WSDLs? (This is for an app that is a 'Consumer' as well as 'Producer' of WebServices).

2) Should we use one-time generated POJOs, or should we write add a Maven Plugin (or Ant) that auto generates the POJOs before each time "compile" task is invoked.

3) Should we have contents of XSDs files pasted into WSDLs? or should the WSDLs "import" the XSD files?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The best would be to create a dedicated project/library that only stores xsd and wsdl files and add it as dependency to module where you want to generate POJOs.
2. Maven plugins are already available, for example cxf-codegen-plugin or wsdl2java-maven-plugin. These are working well and you can customize how POJOs are generated.
3. Import XSD into WSDL.